# How to set a standard i18n locale using spring-boot and thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I integrated i18n to my application using the following config:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/i18n/application");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

I set up properties for "en" and "de" and everything is working fine so far.

If I enter the page from spain for example I only see the placeholder from my html file. But instead of this I want to achieve that the standard language is english ("en") for languages/countries with no existing property config. So I tried this:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}
```

It sets the default to english as I want but now every page (also with existing property for the special language) is displayed in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo have to delete this

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}
```

And add in `src\main\resources\i18n` the default `application.properties` in English

That should fix your problem